# Add multiple members to powershell hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, hashtable

I have a CSV file that contains subnet information that I will use to populate a CSV file that has server information in it. I'm starting by importing the subnet information and when processing it, I'm trying to add multiple members to the initial hashtable, but it is not behaving as expected.
The following code processes the first item as expected, creating a new column with the correct information. The code indicates that it processes at least through two more sections, but the members are not added. How do I change the code to allow the creation of multiple members to a single array? The goal is to have each subnet's gateway field (column) be unique to that subnet.

The purpose of the five variables (variableA-E) is to mimic what is occuring in the real code. The real code runs comparisons from the hashtable, but that is not neccessary. I'm willing to change that portion if needed.

```
CSV file contents:
NetworkName,Subnet,VLANID,Gateway,VLAN
Servers,"192.168.1.0/24","2041","192.168.1.1","ServerVLAN-2041"
Workstations,"192.168.2.0/24","1001","192.168.2.1","WorkstationVLAN-1001"
DMZ,"172.16.0.0/28","340","172.16.0.1","DMZVLAN-340"
Servers,"192.168.3.0/24","2043","192.168.3.1","ServerVLAN-2043"
Workstations,"192.168.4.0/24","1004","192.168.4.1","WorkstationVLAN-1004"
DMZ,,,,
```

CODE:

```
$csvfile = "C:\temp\testfile.csv"
$hashArray = Import-CSV $csvfile

$variableA = "192.168.1.0"
$variableB = "192.168.2.0"
$variableC = "192.168.3.0"
$variableD = "172.16.0.1"
$variableE = "192.168.5.0"

$hashArray | % {
if ($_.subnet) { $variable = ($_.subnet).split("/")[0] }
Else { $variable = $null }
if ($variable -eq $variableA -and $variable -ne $null)
{
    $_ | add-member "ServerGW1" -NotePropertyValue $_.gateway
    Write-Host "Added Server gateway 1: "$_.gateway -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

if ($variable -eq $variableC -and $variable -ne $null)
{
    $_ | add-member "ServerGW2" -NotePropertyValue $_.gateway
    Write-Host "Added Server gateway 2: "$_.gateway -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

if ($variable -eq $variableB -and $variable -ne $null)
{
    $_ | add-member "WorkstationGW1" -NotePropertyValue $_.gateway
    Write-Host "Added Workstation gateway 1: "$_.gateway -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

if ($variable -eq $variableD -and $variable -ne $null)
{
    $_ | add-member "DMZGW1" -NotePropertyValue $_.gateway
    Write-Host "Added DMZ gateway 1: "$_.gateway -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

if ($variable -eq $variableE -and $variable -ne $null)
{
    $_ | add-member "WorkstationGW2" -NotePropertyValue $_.gateway
    Write-Host "Added Workstation gateway 2: "$_.gateway -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
}
$hashArray | Out-GridView
```

Out-GridView OUTPUT:

[image: OutGrid Results]

Console OUTPUT:

[image: Console output]

Expected output:
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: There is probably copy&paste error. You add "WorkstationGW1" property when conditions for  $variableE and  $variableB are satisfied.

Comment: @cezarypiatek Yes, I changed it in the code. Thanks!

Comment: mklement0 beat me to it but why would you want uniquely named properties for your objects? Best practice is to define your base object class and member variable and leave them static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out-GridView uses properties from the first object to render columns. All new columns (except ServerGW1) are missing because are not initialized in the first object in your $hashArray. You can initialize with $null value all properties for all rows or provide a list of properties to select before you output your result to Out-GridView

```
$hashArray | Select-Object NetworkName,Subnet,VLANID,Gateway,VLAN, ServerGW1, ServerGW2,WorkstationGW1,WorkstationGW2,DMZGW1  | Out-GridView
```

Init all properties:

```
$hashArray | % {
$variable =if ($_.subnet) {  ($_.subnet).split("/")[0] }Else { $null }
$_ | add-member "ServerGW1" -NotePropertyValue $(if ($variable -eq $variableA){ $_.gateway}Else { $null })
$_ | add-member "ServerGW2" -NotePropertyValue $(if ($variable -eq $variableC){ $_.gateway}Else { $null })
$_ | add-member "WorkstationGW1" -NotePropertyValue $(if($variable -eq $variableB){ $_.gateway}Else { $null })
$_ | add-member "DMZGW1" -NotePropertyValue $(if ($variable -eq $variableD ){ $_.gateway}Else { $null })
$_ | add-member "WorkstationGW2" -NotePropertyValue $(if ($variable -eq $variableE){ $_.gateway}Else { $null })
}
$hashArray | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Ah. So in theory, the $hashArray has all the properties, but Out-GridView is not displaying them?

Comment: This answers the question being asked. But was a good point from mklement0 that objects are returned and not hashtables.

Comment: That's right. All properties was added but are not visible for Out-GridView. You can examine $hashArray with debugger in ISE

Answer (score 1):

To complement [cezarypiatek's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131742/45375), which provides the crucial pointer:

All formatting cmdlets, including `Out-GridView` decide what properties (columns) to show based on the *first* input object, so to guarantee that the all columns of interest are shown, you must ensure that (at least) the first input object contains *all* properties of interest.

With that in mind, here's a streamlined version of your approach that does that:

```
$csvfile = "C:\temp\testfile.csv"
$networks = Import-CSV $csvfile

# Define the subnets and their property names as an ordered hashtable.
$subnets = [ordered] @{
  '192.168.1.0' = 'ServerGW1'
  '192.168.2.0' = 'ServerGW2'
  '192.168.3.0' = 'WorkstationGW1'
  '172.16.0.0' = 'DMZGW1'
  '192.168.4.0' = 'WorkstationGW2'
}

# Add all properties of interest to the input objects, to ensure
# that Out-GridView (or other formatting cmdlets) show them all.
  # Construct an array of property names, where '*' stands for the original properties...
$propNames = @('*') + [string[]] $subnets.Values
  # ... and create augmented objects based on them.
$networks = $networks | Select-Object -property $propNames 

$networks | % {
  # See if the 'subnet' column has a value...
  if ($subnet = if ($_.subnet) { ($_.subnet).split("/")[0] } else { $null }) {
    # ... and, if so, see if a subnet name is defined for the part before '/' ...
    if ($subnets.Contains($subnet)) {
      # ... and, if so, fill the subnet-named property with the subnet address.
      $_.($subnets.$subnet) = $subnet
    }
  }
}
```

- `Import-CSV` doesn't return *hashtables* it returns *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances).
- The code relies on the fact that, in the context of expressions, you can both *assign* to a variable and use the *value* of that assignment, such as in a conditional, as is the case here (`if ($subnet = ...)`).

Comment: Your code is a great improvement upon mine, but I'm still getting the same result: Only one member is added (the first one).

Comment: @McKenning: cezarypiatek's answer contains the crucial pointer; please see my update for an even more streamlined solution that takes that pointer into account.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this example is dynamic, you have just to modify $hashvariable like you want (or load $hashvariable with file if you want)

```
$csvfile ="C:\temp\testfile.csv"
$hashArray = Import-CSV $csvfile

$hashvariable=[ordered]@{"192.168.1.0"="ServerGW1"; "192.168.2.0"="WorkstationGW1"; "192.168.3.0"="ServerGW2"; "172.16.0.1"="DMZGW1";  "192.168.5.0"="WorkstationGW2" }

$hashArray |  
%{
$result=$_ 
$variable = if ($_.subnet -ne $null) {($_.subnet).split("/")[0]} else {""}
foreach ($key in $hashvariable.Keys)
{
   $value=if ($variable -eq $key) {$key} else {""}
   $result | add-member $hashvariable[$key] -NotePropertyValue $value
}

}

$hashArray | Out-GridView
```